# How do I make a 7 with a horizontal line through the middle?

Tags: fonts, formatting

I've been trying to create the 7 I'm used to writing by hand in LaTeX with a horizontal line through the middle. This seems like it should be a simple thing to do, but I don't see any native support for this. This is the look I am trying to get:

[image: 7 with horizontal line through it]

Comment: The easy solution is to find a font that already uses the symbol (a quick search found nothing),  It is not that difficult to overlay symbols, although getting them right for every font size can be difficult.

Answer (score 5):

One can adjust the parameters to your taste.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}

\newcommand{\seven}{\bgroup% in case box 0 being used
  \sbox0{7}\usebox0\llap{\rule[.5\ht0]{.4\wd0}{.05\ht0}\rule{.24\wd0}{0pt}}
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\tiny \seven
\normalsize \seven
\huge \seven
\end{document}
```

[image: overlay]

Comment: In grammar school I learned that number seven is as shown in OP question (that we easily distinguished from number one) ... I wonder, if exist fonts, with such looks of symbol for number seven.

Comment: I found a few fonts which feature crossed 7, but none which also look like LaTeX roman.  Sensa was closest.