# How can I write a 7 with line?

Tags: characters, number

[image]

Is it possible to write (or even better, temporarily redefine) 7 so that it is always output with line in the PDF output? Something like

```
\newcommand{\7}{\sout{7}}
```

generates a line which spans the whole width of the character. The line should be about half of that (see the pic above).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285227/how-do-i-make-a-7-with-a-horizontal-line-through-the-middle

Comment: [Automatically crossing 7's and Z's in mathematical formulae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34500/134144)  and [How do I make a 7 with a horizontal line through the middle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285227/134144)  are related.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see those.